# How can I solve/prove this inequality

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, quadratics

How do I prove this inequality? In the task before, I had to prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality by using complex numbers but I'm kind of lost here.

for $a,b \ge 0$, $\;(a+b)/2 \le=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)/2}$

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(a-b)^2 \geq 0 \rightarrow a^2-2ab+b^2 \geq 0 \rightarrow 2a^2+2b^2-(a+b)^2 \geq 0$
which means 
$$\frac{(a+b)^2}{4} \leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$$
and finally take the square root.

Answer (score 1):

Since you proved *Cauchy-Schwarz* before, apply it  to the vectors $\;\bigl(\frac12,\frac12\bigr)$ and $(a,b)$.